# How to test 'first assignment' of binding in MVVMCross

Tags: ios, xamarin, mvvmcross

I have a custom MvxConvertingTargetBinding which performs an animation (fade in/fade out) on the visibility of a bound UIView. I am using this binding on some buttons on a UITableViewCell. The intent is that the user taps on the button, some rule changes in the mode, and the button disappears (and another button appears in its place).

The binding captures, during assignment of the binding value to the control - whether or not this is the 'first time' the binding has been applied. If it's first-time, then I DONT animate the visibility. This works well, because I don't want to see my table cells appear in the grid, then have all their buttons fade-in - the point on the binding is to fade the buttons when the underlying model changes during user-interaction... 
This works fine.

The problem arises, when my Cell is 're-used' by the TableViewSource. The binding is re-used, and it's no longer considered 'first time' - so the buttons get animated. This has the effect of as you are scrolling up and down in the list, all the buttons are 'fading in' as they scroll into view... as you can imagine, it looks terrible.

How can I resolve this in a clean fashion?

I thought about putting some code within the TableViewSource, to test for re-use, then on the re-used cell, accessing the binding-set, and trying to 'reset' all the bindings... but there is no way to access the collection of bindings from the MvxFluentBindingDescriptionSet definition.

Any ideas?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok - I cobbled together a solution...

Still, if someone knows of a way native MVVMCross solution for this, please feel free to provide a better answer.

Thankfully, MVVMCross assigns NULL to the MvxTableViewCell.DataContext at the end  of it's life - so I can use this to indicate that a cell binding should be 'reset'. I also get around the inability to access the list of targetbindings in the binding-set by using a static property (kinda gross I know, but hey, it's pretty obvious when you look at the code what's going on - and this is UI still so not a big deal for unit testing.)

This is the idea (pseudo-code):

```
MyMvxConvertingTargetBinding.SetValueImpl:
  if 'is_first_time' then 
    // don't animate the first-time binding of a view. Simple.
    set view value, clear 'is_first_time' and return.
  if 'ISRESETTING' then 
    // this is to ensure the View has the correct value, 
    // but is not animated when the table-view-cell is 
    // being removed from the table. It also resets the first-time state
    // so that when a new DataContext is assigned, it will perform
    // clean 'first-time' behavior.
    reset 'is_first_time' to TRUE, set view value, and return
  if is_first_time 
    then set view value and return
  otherwise, animate setting of view value

MvxTableViewCell.DataContext.Set:
  if current DataContext is not null and new DataContext is null:
    // This allows the TargetBinding to capture the fact that
    // the source data-model is being disconnected
    static MyMvxConvertingTargetBinding.ISRESETTING = TRUE
  Assign base.DataContext
  finally static MyMvxConvertingTargetBinding.ISRESETTING = FALSE
```

Finally, the idea would be in any MvxTableViewCell when you use one of your special 'animated bindings', make sure you override the DataContext and wrap the 'base.set; in a try/catch which toggles the 'ISRESETTING', just like in the pseudo-code. This works well.

Another problem that this actually fixes, is where a re-used table-view-cell is still animating a child view to the 'hiddden' state, when the cell gets re-used, and hence re-animated into the 'visible' state. This causes conflicting animations which may result in the cell appearing in the table with it's child View hidden when it should be visible!

What would be nice, would be a service that allowed an MvxTargetBinding to capture changes in the DataContext of the model pertaining to the given binding. Then we wouldn't need the static field approach used here.